# Marshmallow SQLAlchemy load without interacting with database

Tags: python, serialization, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

When using the `ModelSchema.load` method an object will interact with the database.

For example, when one does the following:

```
author = Author(name="Chuck Paluhniuk")
author_schema = AuthorSchema()
book = Book(title="Fight Club", author=author)
session.add(author)
session.add(book)
session.commit()

dump_data = author_schema.dump(author).data
print(dump_data)
# {'books': [123], 'id': 321, 'name': 'Chuck Paluhniuk'}

load_data = author_schema.load(dump_data, session=session)
```

The above code will cause marshmallow-sqlalchemy to contact the database. I want to avoid any and all database interaction when using `load`. I want to manage the object myself, adding it to a session if I care to and leaving it outside if not.

I have tried the `transient=True` argument to `load`. For example:

```
 load_data = author_schema.load(dump_data, session=session, transient=True)
```

I thought this was suppose to blindly instantiate the object without making database calls, or even binding the object to a session, but this is not true. Marshmallow-sqlalchemy still makes database calls even with this argument set to true.

Comment: My read of the documentation (and the code) agrees that transient=True shouldn't be making database queries. I think you'll have to provide some evidence that it's talking to the database. Try passing in session=object() or something to force an exception (which should produce a stacktrace if it actually is attempting to access the db)

Comment: Without doing what you suggest, I get this error: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance <> with identity key (<class 'app.model'>, (1,), None) conflicts with persistent instance` when trying to load a second example of the same class, which makes me think it is trying to work with the database. I'll try to do what you suggest as well.

Comment: Ah, you're probably dealing with autoflush, which isn't really marshmallow-sqlalchemy's fault as much as just the way sqlalchemy's autoflush works.. you could also try wrapping the whole thing in a `with session.no_autoflush:` context block to tell sqlalchemy to chill out with the autoflushing behavior

Comment: Even if it is flushing, though, this object shouldn't get flushed, because it should never get added to the session (if it is transient). At least that's what I would expect.

Comment: I've experienced a lot of behavior that makes me believe that flask-sqlalchemy may be doing something under the hood that adds things to the session when you'd think they wouldn't be. I've got a lot of code that's inside a `no_autoflush` block when I'd swear it shouldn't be in the session ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Currently facing the exact same issue

Comment: The best answer is that of Steven Fuhry. Frankly, the consequence of all the unexpected behavior I get from SQL alchemy, I have personally started leaning toward no longer using orm in a complex fashion. There are just so many gotchas and headaches in SQL alchemy that it kind of defeats the purpose of creating an abstraction layer.